# What's the equivalent of MatLab/Octave filt/bode in scipy?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, signal-processing

To create a digital system that could be used e.g. in bode or spectrum in matlab or octave I could use:

```
b = [1,0.1,0.2,0.3]
a = [1,-1]
sys = filt(b,a)
bode(sys)
spectrum(sys)
```

What will be the scipy equivalent for this command(s)?

Comment: For reference: links to [`filt`](http://mathworks.com/help/control/ref/filt.html) and [`bode`](http://mathworks.com/help/control/ref/bode.html) documentation for MATLAB. By the way, the examples for [`scipy.signal.bode`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.bode.html) may be relevant to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options, you can use [`scipy.signal.bode`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.bode.html) or [`python-control.bode`](http://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/control.bode.html#control.bode) or [`harold.bodeplot`](http://harold.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tut_freq_domain.html#harold.bodeplot).

Comment: How should I create digital system (using a and b) to supply for scipy.signal.bode?